# error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'A' used

Tags: c++

I have a question related to my C/C++ code. I tried some researches but there was no specific answer for my problem. I hope you will response to my question as soon as possible.

Here is my full code in C language:

```
 #include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define M 500
#define N 500
int
main ()
{
  //set number of threads here
  //omp_set_num_threads(8);
  int i, j, k;
  double sum;
  double **A, **B, **C;

  A = malloc (M * sizeof (double *));
  B = malloc (M * sizeof (double *));
  C = malloc (M * sizeof (double *));
  for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
      A[i] = malloc (N * sizeof (double));
      B[i] = malloc (N * sizeof (double));
      C[i] = malloc (N * sizeof (double));
    }
  double start, end;
  for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
          A[i][j] = j * 1;
          B[i][j] = i * j + 2;
          C[i][j] = j - i * 2;
        }
    }
  start = omp_get_wtime ();
  for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
          sum = 0;
          for (k = 0; k < M; k++)
            {

              sum += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
          C[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }

  end = omp_get_wtime ();
  printf ("Time of computation: %f\n", end - start);

  cin.get ();
  return 0;
}
```

The code terminates because of some bugs. 
The result of the code is given here:

```
error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'A' used

error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'B' used

error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'C' used
```

Please consider my question :)

Best Regards.

Comment: When you say 'the code terminates', I think you mean 'the compiler gives the following errors', yes? The compiler errors should give line references. Which lines do they refer to? As far as I can tell from the code you pasted above, `A`, `B` and `C` are each correctly initialised by the `malloc`.

Comment: I don't think your code compiles using a C compiler. Tag your question with C++ as the program is C++(Because of `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;`)

Comment: This is neither valid C nor C++ code.  Are you sure those are the only errors reported?  It seems likely that these are precipitated by earlier errors, like the invalid assignment of `void*` to a `double**` without a cast (in C++).  If you are using C++, you'd do better to use `new` in any case.  What version of VC++ are you using?

Comment: @clifford, i am usring visual studio proffessional 2013. the above code is written in C++. 
Please, run that and give me your feedback. many thanks again.

Comment: @abligh yes, by the code terminates i do mean the compiler gives the following errors. The lines that refers are the three lines after the row double **A, **B, **C; many thanks.

Comment: `run that and give me your feedback` Ran it, [here's the feedback](http://rextester.com/UNZ11430). I don't see the errors you cite, but there's a different set of errors, those predicted by @Clifford.

Comment: Update your question; copy & paste the entire content of the "Output" tab window (Alt+2 if it is not currently shown) - this is a plain text output of the build and is often more informative than the filtered "Error List" tab and is easier to copy and paste.  Check that the code you have posted is the code to which these errors belong, because it does not produce those errors for me, and it is not valid C++.  Add the cast for the malloc() calls, and it builds and runs - the evidence is that you have posted the wrong code or the wrong errors, and it remains bad C++.

Comment: The trivial use of OpenMP timing functions does not really justify the use of the openmp, parallel-processing or multithreading tags.  The question is not related to those in any manner.

Answer (score 0):

malloc() returns a void pointer, you have to cast it:

```
  A = (double**) malloc (M * sizeof (double *));
  B = (double**) malloc (M * sizeof (double *));
  C = (double**) malloc (M * sizeof (double *));
  for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
      A[i] = (double*) malloc (N * sizeof (double));
      B[i] = (double*) malloc (N * sizeof (double));
      C[i] = (double*) malloc (N * sizeof (double));
    }
```

if you are using c++ maybe is better to use "new" instead of malloc:

```
  A = new double* [M];
  B = new double* [M];
  C = new double* [M];
  for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
      A[i] = new double[N];
      B[i] = new double[N];
      C[i] = new double[N];
    }
```

Comment: if you use c++, it is better to use std:: container like std::vector or std::array than new.